# Return multiple values from one function in swift (in the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind) func

Tags: ios, swift, function, uicollectionview, return-value

Does anyone know how to return 2 values from the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function?  This function is part of the UICollectionView when adding a header and footer.  I am trying to return the footer and header within the same function.

Thanks!!

Comment: before taking a look at the actual question: you need to *upload* your picture, not post a link to your ***local*** file. Secondly: do **not** post a "picture of code"!

Comment: Yes, show your code, but the answer is, you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to / should return two values in one call, but rather return either the footer **or** the header depending on the `kind`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter {
        // return footer
    } else if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        // return header
    }
}
```

To add both footer and header you have to additionally tick both boxes in the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Will it still display both the header and footer? Or only the header or footer?  I have been looking for hours on how to add both a header and footer in a supplementary view w/in a UICollectionView in swift and the closest I got was to something in objective-c, which I did not understand.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/ Here is the link that was closet to adding a header and footer, but was in objective-c.

Comment: @SkylarBjörn I added a screenshot - you have to tell the collection view that you want both header and footer

Comment: Thanks!! I am now getting an error that says "Expected declaration", and fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.  Do you know why it is nil? I checked the boxes to make sure there was a header and footer and I also created subclasses, etc. The expected declaration is also appearing at the very bottom of the screen.

Comment: @SkylarBjörn without more information I cannot help you, no. You may want to create a pastebin with your current code marking the lines where the errors / crashes occur.

Comment: nope, but I feel like it's a small error that's causing this to happen

Comment: @SkylarBjörn If you feel that error is not strictly related to this question, please accept my answer and ask a new separate question regarding the new problem or alternatively include the current error if you think it has to do with this exact question.